# Tuple index out of range, trying to reshape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to follow the youtube tutorial from the link below, but I'm getting the error: "Tuple index out of range" I've compared my code to the video and it seems to match. It's the very last line of code that returns the error. I did create and compile the model, had to remove that code in order to post. Any ideas on how to correct this?

```
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuZY9q-aKLw

#Load data
company = 'FB'

start = dt.datetime(2012,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)

data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)

#Prepare Data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data['Close'].values.reshape(-1,1))

prediction_days=60

x_train = []
y_train = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[x, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))


#Test the model accuracy

test_start = dt.date(2020,1,1)
test_end = dt.datetime.now()

test_data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', test_start, test_end)
actual_prices = test_data['Close'].values

total_dataset = pd.concat((data['Close'], test_data['Close']), axis=0)

model_inputs = total_dataset[len(total_dataset)- len(test_data) - prediction_days:].values
model_inputs = model_inputs.reshape(-1, 1)
model_inputs = scaler.transform(model_inputs)

#Make predictions on test data

x_test = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(model.inputs)):
    x_test.append(model_inputs[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
    
x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
```

Comment: What shape are you trying to reshape `x_test` into?

Comment: You need to check `x_test.shape`.  Also `x_test.dtype`